# Запятая при вводных словах, начинающих обособление

Tags: пунктуация

Я, например,только сейчас собирая материал об участниках войны, которые захоронены на кладбище д.Ново, узнала много интересных фактов. Так расставлены знаки препинания у автора. По- моему, запятая после "например" не нужна, так как начинает деепричастный оборот. И "только сейчас" перенесла бы перед словом узнала. Подскажите, как правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я, например, только сейчас собирая материал об участниках войны,
>   которые захоронены на кладбище д. Ново, узнала много интересных
>   фактов. Так расставлены знаки препинания у автора.

Не хватает запятой после слов "только сейчас" (которые, правда, совсем  не к месту).

ВАРИАНТ:

*Собирая в последнее время материал об участниках войны, похороненных на кладбище д. Ново, я узнала много интересных фактов.*

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, такой вариант подойдет:

Я, например, только сейчас,  собирая материал об участниках войны, захороненных на кладбище д.Ново, узнала много интересных фактов.

Здесь деепричастный оборот уточняет значение наречия "сейчас".

Comment: Получается, что только сейчас относится "узнала много интересных фактов". Наверное, так и есть. Спасибо